Docker build: npm install hangs on npm info ok
I updated my strapi app in docker but now when I build it (on my Ubuntu 22.04 server), it seems to hang at the very end. This is my Dockerfile:
FROM node:18.17.1-alpine as build
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /opt/
COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json ./
ENV PATH /opt/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
RUN npm install -g npm@10.9.2
RUN npm i --omit=dev --verbose
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY ./ .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:18.17.1-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /opt/
COPY --from=build /opt/node_modules ./node_modules
ENV PATH /opt/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY --from=build /opt/app ./
EXPOSE 1337
CMD ["npm", "run","start"]

And this is the output I get:
added 1679 packages, and audited 1681 packages in 13m

npm verbose cwd /opt
npm verbose os Linux 5.15.0-46-generic
npm verbose node v18.17.1
npm verbose npm  v10.9.2
npm verbose exit 0
npm info ok

It hangs there without exiting.
The app installs fine when I run it locally (Ubuntu 24.04) outside of Docker.

Can you comment out everything, build the image and comment in one line until you find the problem? Do you use Docker Desktop? What OS do you use? Is this your problem: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/1946
